# Сохранение текста в документ формата DOCX, ODT

Tags: c#, uwp

Кто знает как можно текст из RichEditBox сохранить в DOCX и ODT форматы ?
Может есть примеры сохранения в docx или odt в интернете(ничего не нашел). Или какая нибудь библиотека.

Comment: Ну вот на вскидку пару решений для работы с docx https://github.com/xceedsoftware/DocX  https://github.com/OfficeDev/Open-XML-SDK